# Reading and streaming tweets in R language

Tags: r, csv, twitter

I've been trying to capture tweets in using R language in Rstudio. I'm using a csv file as keyword input which has keywords into the code. However, when it collects tweets it shows tweets in other languages or in javascript form. I've tried converting the words to a javascript format, using an excel sheet as input, changing system language. Changed the code more than once and used different methods, downloaded different versions of Rstudio.
None of that worked and i'm stuck. I have seen others using Rstudio to capture tweets in Arabic and it worked. We both were using the same exact code so i don't understand what went wrong.

```
library(ROAuth) 
library(RCurl)

requestURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # From dev.twitter.com
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 

??ROAuth 
my_oauth = OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumer_key,
                        consumerSecret = consumer_secret,
                        requestURL = requestURL,
                        accessURL = accessURL,
                        authURL = authURL)
my_oauth$handshake(curl=getCurlHandle())


save(my_oauth, file = "my_oauth.Rdata")
load("my_oauth.Rdata")

####################################

library(stringi)
dat <- read.csv("streets.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
keyword = stri_trans_nfkc(dat)


####################################

library(streamR) 

filterStream(oauth=my_oauth, timeout = 120, track = keyword, file.name =    "tweetsSTA12-1.json") 

tweetsdf = parseTweets("tweetsSTA12-1.json", simplify = TRUE) 
View(tweetsdf)

library(xlsx) 
write.xlsx(tweetsdf , "tweetsTestSTA12-1.xlsx",sheetName = "tweets", row.names = FALSE)


write.csv(tweetsdf, "tweetsTestSTA12-1.csv")
```

Comment: Can you capture English language tweets?

Comment: What's your operating system? I've got no pblm collecting tweets in arabic here on macbook. 
Can you try `library(rtweet) ; search_tweets(q = "")` with your keyword between the "", written in arabic and tell us what you get in the text column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i tried it and faced the same issue for some reason

Comment: @Rem.3 Then Arabic likely has nothing to do with your problem, and you might want to remove it from your title.  It could be leading people down the wrong path to try to help you.

Comment: @ColinFAY i've tried it and it's giving me the same results. symbols, foreign languages and javascripts. I'm running on Windows 10.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure. however i'm focusing on gathering arabic tweets. will remove it though. thank you very much

Comment: I gave you an upvote.  Just made that suggestion because a more generic question might have a greater chance of being answered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you very much i appreciate it!